# Which one is faster null check using ==operator or ?. operator

Tags: c#, optimization, comparison

I'm a C# developer and I'm looking for optimization little by little

```
 if (tksPesin.prmBilgi != null && tksPesin.prmBilgi.Any())
```

Or

```
if (tksPesin.prmBilgi?.Any() ?? false)
```

I try to improve my codes and I'm looking for tiny and small optimization.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/. In short: you are pretty sure faster by just *measuring* then us *guessing* about your environment. Furthermor you shouldn't strive for micro-optimizations, but for actual business-value.

Comment: I wonder what's @EricLippert's opinion, for his rant being used as a weapon for shutting down questions on this site.

Answer (score 3):

These two things are not the same; in two very important ways:

1. `!= null` *may or may not be using a custom operator*; `?.` always uses the same logic as `is not null`
2. in the first version, you access `tksPesin.prmBilgi` **twice**; we can't see `tksPesin.prmBilgi`, so we don't know if that has a hidden http call, `Thread.Sleep`, etc

So: there *can* be differences making the `?.` version faster.

However, if you *really* want to know which is faster: *measure them* in your specific scenario. In reality, though, we would never expect the `?.` version to be slower in any reasonable scenario.

If you wanted to long-hand the first version to be comparable to the `?.` version, you would use:

```cs
var tmp = tksPesin.prmBilgi; // important: access .prmBilgi once only
if (tmp is not null && tmp.Any()) // important: avoid custom != operator
{
    // ...
}
```

however, this does *not* give you any advantage over the `?.` version.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (tksPesin.prmBilgi?.Any() ?? false)
```

Will be compiled to:

```
 if (tksPesin.prmBilgi != null && tksPesin.prmBilgi.Any())
```

So there is no difference. You can use https://sharplab.io/ to see how those things are compiled.

Comment: see, that's just not true; it will be compiled to something more like `var tmp = tksPesin.prmBilgi; if (tmp is not null && tmp.Any())` - these differences *can matter*

Comment: As Marc mentions the elvis-operator is short-cirtcuiting.